# How to resolve "uvicorn: command not found error" coming while creating FASTAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

when I try to create an app in FastAPI using the command "**uvicorn main:app --reload**", I get this **uvicorn command not found error**. My python version is 3.8.9.

when I tried installing uvicorn using "**pip install uvicorn**". It is successfully installed and up to date. But giving command not found error. How can I work with uvicorn command?

Answer (score 3):

Run uvicorn as a module: python -m uvicorn main:app --reload

Answer (score 1):

I recommend adding more information such as whether you are installing it globally, to your user, in a virtual environment, or in a docker container.

In either case, as another user mentioned in a comment, the module is not being installed in the python path that it is lookin at.

If you have Python 2.7 installed, it is possible pip is installing it to that path and you may need to use pip3.

```
pip3 install uvicorn
```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot find your uvicorn installation. If you installed it in a virtual environment, you have to call it from that virtual env.

Comment: Hi @Nora, I've tried after activating my virtual environment only. Checked the version of uvicorn also using 'python -m uvicorn --version' and got the result as "Running uvicorn 0.18.3 with CPython 3.8.9 on Linux". But still uvicorn not found command is comming in linux bash terminal

Comment: I replicated your steps. Create virtual env, activate virtual env, pip install uvicorn, check command line uvicorn version, and it all worked. 
Please check if 
/path/to/your/venv/bin is in your PATH variable
```echo $PATH```
You should see a uvicorn directory in that bin folder if you open it.
If it is not there, do the steps I described in the begin of this comment, and retry

Comment: Yes , I tried "echo $PATH". venv//bin/ path is available but I'm not able to see the uvicorn directory inside bin. How to set that?

Answer (score 0):

That is because your Python bin folder is not in your path. You first need to find out where your Python bin is located.

For example, I use a Mac with the latest macOS 13.3 and I use the pre-installed Python 3.9. It is installed in `~/Library/Python/3.9/`. When you run `pip install` you can get that information from the `site-packages`, e.g. after running pip install I see the result like `~/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages` then I can add `~/Python/3.9/bin` to my PATH.